# ES6, export all imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a central file to coagulate all of my files. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing this within es6, or even the right approach but my idea is like so :

```
import files1.file from '../file1/index';
import files2.file from '../file2/index';
import files3.file from '../file3/index';    

export {* as files};
```

This does not seem to work, I'm wondering if there is some way of doing this or equivalent.

Comment: There is no special syntax to export all imports.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this? Or did you want to avoid it?

```
import files1.file from '../file1/index';
import files2.file from '../file2/index';
import files3.file from '../file3/index';    

let files = { file1: files1.file,
              file2: files2.file,
              file3: files3.file };

export default files;
```

I am not exactly sure this is going to work but that's what I would try.

Comment: I am exactly sure this is not going to work, because `import files1.file` is invalid syntax. It would have been easy enough to test this.